# Laravel - Where should I put user uploaded personal/sensitive documents?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, I am putting all files in my public directory which means that anyone can download the file.

However, I don't want anyone else to see that file other than the user who created it. As of right now, I have no control over that. Maybe if I store it in another directory, I will be using middleware to protect it.

But I'm stuck on the part where I can upload the user-uploaded files.

Where is the best directory to put them? I don't have an external server I just have a VPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has a `storage` folder designed especially for this case. It's not available from outside your server and you will have to serve the files from it through Laravel.

Comment: What is the base path for this? How can I move the uploaded file into this folder? `$baseDir = 'storage';`  doesn't work. How can I access the folder using PHP?

Comment: `storage_path()` helper function will get you into the storage folder